# How to create a independent service separated from (App) in android

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have a **service** which runs in **foreground** and has a **notification** bar.

If I close the App the Service continue running and this is great.
but the service is stopped when the app crash.

I have overrded the **onDestroy** but this is not called when app crash.
Then tha question is..

How can I get the Service continue running if the app crashes?

Answer (score 0):

If u return `return Service.START_STICKY;`  in the `onStartComman`
Your service will get recreated everytime it crashes;
In case u dont want that register a broadcast receiver in ur manifest and start your service via this broadcast receiver

Comment: I have  return Start_Sticky and this is not  recreated when app crashes

Comment: really? thats weird it works for me try to register it via broadcast receiver tho that way the service wontbe bound to ur application...

Comment: maybe the solution to my problem is the process attribute in manifest for the service but i am having troubles too

Comment: maybe you could add your manifest, your main class and your service to the op?